# Where are my commit messages after a merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches which I merged together: issue-x and hotfix-a

`-|- master
 |\_________ hotfix-a
 |_________/ issue-x`

Both branches have the same origin, but the history of hotfix-a has some changes, which issue-x doesn't have. Now I merged issue-x into hotfix-a and resolved the conflicts. I used Xamarin Studio for merging (no command line).

If I look after the status I see the conflicts, which should be resolved, the new files created in issue-x and all the changed files. What I don't see are the commit messages for each file done in issue-x.

Where are my commit messages gone? Do I something wrong? I haven't commited the changes after the merge yet.

**Edit:**

If you want to make a commit you can see all files which have changed. You can select the files and make a commit. You can select each file and add a commit message:

[image: commit message for each file]

Comment: *[...] the commit messages for each file [...]* Commit messages are associated to commits, not files. Could you clarify?

Comment: To see the history of commit messages, you usually just need to call `git log`.  Since you haven't commited the merge yet, you should be able to see the commits in the `issue-x` branch using `git log issue-x`.

Comment: @Jubobs: When I make a commit I can add a commit message for each file. See edited question for this.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I can't switch the branch now. I get: *Branch switch failed. Unmerged path: Project/SomeFile.cs*. Do I have to commit the conflicts? I think the log history should be available in issue-x branch. I want the log history also in hotfix-a branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to switch the branch but I got

> Branch switch failed. Unmerged path: Project/SomeFile.cs.

Then I tried to commit the conflicts, which failed with

> Cannot commit on a repo with state: MERGING

Now I added the conflicting files as described [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge/):

```
git add yourDirectory/yourFile.ext
```

With this I was able to switch the branches. With `git status` I got the notice

> All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
>     (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Then I selected all files in the GUI (Xamarin Studio) and made one commit message for all files and commited (this is the concluded commit). Now I can see in the log the commit messages of the files from branch issue-x.

It seems that a GUI for GIT can't handle all cases. Here resolving a conflict can only done by using the command line. No reason for downvoting if you haven't done this before. Instead provide a solution or a hint in the right direction!

One question still remains:

Why can I find in the log of some files the concluded commit message and in other files not?